# Соединение клиента и сервера на основе sfml

Tags: c++, сеть, tcp, sfml

Недавно ради эксперимента сделал две программы - клиент и сервер, грубо говоря. Программы очень простые: клиент выводит несколько кружков на экран, один из которых управляется на клавиши самим пользователем(перемещение в 2D пространстве), и несколько кружков другого цвета - все подключенные к серверу пользователи, кроме нашего. Сервер принимает подключения в отдельном потоке, и в случае наличия подключений, отправляет клиентам данные о всех кружках, кроме их собственного, предварительно получив данные местоположения кружка самого пользователя.
Код прилагается:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
void thr_serverConnect(bool& metka, string Ip, int port,CircleShape& ball, vector<CircleShape>& vec) {
    TcpSocket socket;
    while (socket.connect(Ip, port) == Socket::Status::Error) { true; }
    int num = 0;
    int countOfFalls = 0;
    while (metka) {
        socket.send(&ball.getPosition(), sizeof(Vector2f));  //Отправляет свои данные -> получает количество клиентов -> получает их данные
        size_t received;
        socket.receive(&num, sizeof(int), received);
        while (num - 1 > vec.size()) { vec.push_back(CircleShape()); int i = vec.size() - 1; vec[i].setFillColor(Color::Blue);  vec[i].setRadius(10); }
        for (int i = 0; i < num-1; i++) {
            Vector2f temp;
            socket.receive(&temp, sizeof(Vector2f), received);
            vec.at(i).setPosition(temp);
        }
        if (countOfFalls == 10) { cout << "Server fall connected" << endl; break; }
        if (received <= 0) { countOfFalls++; Sleep(100); }
        else { countOfFalls = 0; }
    }
}
 
//Серверная часть моего проекта. 
void thr1(TcpSocket& socket, vector<CircleShape>& vec, bool& metka,bool& connected) {
    bool ready = true;
    Vector2f ballclient;
    size_t received;
    socket.receive(&ballclient, sizeof(Vector2f), received);
    CircleShape ballclient2;
    ballclient2.setPosition(ballclient);
    vec.push_back(ballclient2);
    int ID = vec.size() - 1;
    int t = vec.size();
    int countOfFalls = 0;
    socket.send(&t, sizeof(int));
    while (metka) {
        t = vec.size();
        for (int i = 0; i != t; i++) {
            if (ID != i) {
                socket.send(&vec.at(i).getPosition(), sizeof(Vector2f));
            }
        }
        socket.receive(&ballclient, sizeof(Vector2f), received);
        CircleShape ballclient2;
        ballclient2.setPosition(ballclient);
        vec[ID] = ballclient2;
        if (countOfFalls == 10) { 
            connected = false;
            break;
        }
        if (received <= 0) { countOfFalls++; }
        else { countOfFalls = 0; }
        Sleep(10);
        int t = vec.size();
        socket.send(&t, sizeof(int));
    }
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    vector<CircleShape>csl;
    list<bool>metki;
    bool ProgramOn = true;
    TcpListener listener;
    while (true) {
        if (listener.listen(15000) == Socket::Status::Done) {
            TcpSocket* socket = new TcpSocket;
            listener.accept(*socket);
            metki.push_back(new bool(true));
            //bool& i = ;
            cout << "New connect: " << socket->getRemoteAddress() << ":" << socket->getRemotePort() << endl;
            cout << "Now we have " << metki.size() << " connections" << endl;
            thread NetConnect(thr1, ref(*socket), ref(csl), ref(ProgramOn), ref(*metki.end()));
            NetConnect.detach();
        };
    }
    ProgramOn = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Первая функция запускается в клиенте в отдельном потоке и служит для соединения и отправки/получения данных сервера. Функция перемещения(main-функция) клиента тут не присутсвует, так как в ней нет ничего, связанного с сетью. Просто изменение позиции ball-а, который передается в поток.

Итак, суть проблемы:
Программа полностью работает на ip адресах типа 127.0.0.1 и моем локальном ip-адресе(адресер в закрытой сети роутера, где присутсвуют все устройства, подлюченные к нему), также работает на виртуальной машине-моим пк, если использовать локальный ip, также работает между моим пк-пк, находящемся в этой же локальной сети, если использовать локальный ip. Есть еще сеть, созданная Hamachi на перманентной основе - она тоже подходит для подключения, но только на моем пк(это так, к слову). Проблема в том, что между моим пк и пк, находящемся в другой сети, образно, подключенным к другому роутеру, связь настроить не получается. Просто бесконечное ожидание, даже попытки подключиться не происходит. Если что, то порт на моем пк(всегда сервер запускался именно у меня) открыт на входящие соединения. На счет портов внелокльного пк - ничего не могу сказать.
Я недостаточно хорошо знаю устройство tcp сетей, а потому не могу выявить ошибку сам, пробовал изучать некоторую литературу, но ничего не смог для себя выделить. В Интернете тоже искал, но ничего конкретного сказано не было. Я не пробовал подключать внелокальный пк через Hamach-евский ip и не уверен, сработает это или нет. Я не знаю, должен ли создавать разрешения доступа к портам моего приложения на внелокальном пк. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что именно я сделал не так.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь :)

Comment: На удалённой машине порт 15000 открыт в файерволе?

Comment: @PakUula Вот в том то и дело, что скорее всего нет. То есть, необходимо создать правило для приложения, чтобы был доступ ко всем портам, для возможности подключения? Но это не требуется, скажем, в локальной сети?

Comment: Адреса на другой сети никак не связаны с текущей. Могут быть даже равны, и клиенты могут  иметь одинаковые адреса. В роутерах нужны переадресации порта 15000. И адрес можно только указывать на адрес чужого роутера, а не на его клиента.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Адреса, разумеется, я использовал внешние(если мы говорим об подключении двух пк в разных сетях). То есть, клиент указывал ip моей сети и 15000 порт. Требуется еще какая-то переадресация?

Comment: В роутерах входящие соединение с портом 15000 должны быть переадресованы на локальную точку своего клиента/сервера.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Понял. Сейчас буду разбираться. Спасибо за совет

Comment: [Как открыть порты через Хамачи](http://hamachi-pc.ru/instructions/kak-otkryt-porty-cherez-khamachi.html)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Большое спасибо за ссылку :)

Comment: Если получится без хамачи (который довольно противный), то лучше без него. *"порт на моем пк(всегда сервер запускался именно у меня) открыт на входящие соединения"* Этого должно быть достаточно. Проверьте на какой-нибудь игре, что правильно открываете порты (да хоть на майнкрафте). *"На счет портов внелокльного пк - ничего не могу сказать"* Это не нужно, открытые порты нужны только серверу. Еще убедитесь, что используете правильный IP - не локальный, а внешний (см. https://ifconfig.me/ ).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, получилось без хамачи. Помогло добавление переадресации на роутере на мой локальный Ip. В ссылке про хамачи просто было расписано, как это сделать. Сейчас добавлю ответ на вопрос, чтобы люди могли найти

Answer (score 0):

С проблемой получилось справиться и вот как. На роутере сделана переадресация для указанного в подключении порта(у меня 15000) на мой локальный адрес(локальный адрес моего пк в локальной сети роутера).
Ссылка, о том, как это сделать(большое спасибо @AlexGlebe):
http://hamachi-pc.ru/instructions/kak-otkryt-porty-cherez-khamachi.html

Порты на пк клиента не были открыты, но это не потребовалось. А вот порт, используемый для подключения ко мне(15000 - в моем случае) открыт для внешний/внутренних подключений через брандмауэр Windows, если что, в ссылке есть информация о том, как это сделать через Hamachi.
Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь :)

Comment: Дык а вы уверены, что после этих манипуляций хамачи вообще нужен?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А хамачи и не нужен. Просто в руководстве от создателей хамачи описано, как сделать переадресацию с роутера на пк